# webpack issue while updating bootstrap v4 to v5

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, bootstrap-5

I have upgrade my angular to v16 from v15, i have also upgrade my ng-bootstarp from v10 to v15 now when im trying to upgrade my bootstrap from v4 to v5 i am getting error.

This is the error i am getting while tring to install bootstrap v5

```bash
PS C:\Users\BP_Kaushik Shukla\Desktop\clone repo\hillsv2cmobile-V2\client> npm install bootstrap@5 --save
```

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!

> npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-builders/custom-webpack@15.0.0 npm

> ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@16.2.12 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli npm ERR!   peer

> @angular/compiler-cli@"^16.0.0" from

> @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular npm ERR!     dev

> @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.12" from the root project npm

> ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"16.2.12" from

> @angular/localize@16.2.12 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/localize

> npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/localize@"^16.0.0" from

> @angular-devkit/build-angular@16.2.12 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular npm ERR!       dev

> @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^16.2.12" from the root project npm

> ERR!     peer @angular/localize@"^16.0.0" from

> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@15.1.2 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap npm ERR!

> @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"15.1.2" from the root project npm ERR!  1

> more (the root project) npm ERR!  2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root

> project) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer

> @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from

> @angular-builders/custom-webpack@15.0.0 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack npm ERR!   dev

> @angular-builders/custom-webpack@"^15.0.0" from the root project npm

> ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:

> @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.10 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli npm ERR!   peer

> @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from

> @angular-builders/custom-webpack@15.0.0 npm ERR!

> node_modules/@angular-builders/custom-webpack npm ERR!     dev

> @angular-builders/custom-webpack@"^15.0.0" from the root project npm

> ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR!

> this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an

> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm

> ERR! npm ERR! For a full report see: npm ERR! C:\Users\BP_Kaushik

> Shukla\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-29T06_00_48_075Z-eresolve-report.txt

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

> C:\Users\BP_Kaushik

> Shukla\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-29T06_00_48_075Z-debug-0.log